# How to retrive From which user is message in Cake?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am making a message system in CakePHP and I have table messages

```
id
from_id
to_id
subject
message
```

to_id is set as FK for user so user can haveMany messages but how can I echo the name of sender if I get only id?

User Model:

```
class User extends AppModel {

public $name = 'User';

public $hasOne = array (
    'UserProfile'=>array(
        'className'=>'UserProfile',
        'foreignKey'=>'id'
    )
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'Message'=>array(
        'className'=>'Message',
        'foreignKey'=>'to_id'
    )
);
}
```

Message Model:

```
class Message extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Message';

public $belongsTo = array (
    'User'=>array(
        'className'=>'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'to_id'
    ),
);
}
```

Message Controller:

```
public function messages(){

    $user = $this->User->find(  'first', array('conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'))));
    $this->set('user', $user);


    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->requert->data['Message']['from_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        debug($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

This needs to store all information about user in array including array Message but in this case I get the arrat Message with:

```
id => 1
from_id => 10
to_id => 7
subject => 'subject'
message => 'body'
```

So how can I extract the name of sender from this id?

Please help?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you will need to use aliases for the classNames.

```
class Message extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Sender' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'from_id'
        ),
        'Receiver' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'to_id'
        )
    );
}

class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'SentMessages' => array(
            'className' => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'from_id'
        ),
        'Messages' => array(
            'className' => 'Message',
            'foreignKey' => 'to_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Your aliases should also be singular! "SentMessage" etc

Comment: I edited the answer. Also @Miskone take a look at the CounterCache feature: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto you should add those columns to your users table